# Error token_not_provided JWT in Laravel login from API

Tags: laravel, jwt

I get token but the problem is when redirected this error will happened : token_not_provided

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/api/login', [
        'form_params' => [
             "email"        => 'niakan@gmail.com',
             "password"     => '123456',
        ]
    ]);

    $res = json_decode( $res->getBody() );
    $token = $res->data->token;

    if ( $res->status == "success" ) {
        $request->headers->set('Authorization', "Bearer $token");
        return redirect('/test2');
    } else {
        abort( 404 );
    }
```

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427106/laravel-how-to-set-custom-header-while-redirecting-to-any-url/36427902

Comment: I want user be login by jwt after requested to api and set Authorization, but didn't works

Comment: It works with : return redirect('/test2/?token=' . $token);

Answer (score 1):

you need to insert the token, not string of "$token".

```
if ( $res->status == "success" ) {
    $request->headers->set('Authorization', "Bearer ". $token);
    return redirect('/test2');
} else {
    abort( 404 );
}
```

note the

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', "Bearer ". $token);
```