# How do i redirect to an external url with headers?

Tags: laravel

How i have  an application which is sitting on `A` server and i would like to allow user to get to another application which is in `B` server with a header of the user information. I have done some tries but i m not getting the header in `B` server. How can i achieve that ya?

Bellow are the codes which i have tried:-

```
return redirect()->away($apiUrl)->header('x-api-token', $token);
```

and

```
$client = new Client();
        $request = $client->request('get', $apiUrl, [
            'headers' => [
                'x-api-user-token' => $userToken
            ]
        ]);
```

Is there a way for me to redirect to an external url with a header?

Comment: It looks like the `away()` method has a parameter for headers, have you tried that? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L147

Comment: You might be doing something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427106/laravel-how-to-set-custom-header-while-redirecting-to-any-url/36427902

Comment: I have tried but its not working.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try the helper method provided by Laravel and it works like a charm for me.

```
return redirect('http://external.url/', 302, [
    'custom-header' => 'custom value'
])
```

If you want to look at the source code please refer 
 `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Helpers.php`

```
/**
 * Get an instance of the redirector.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $to
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($to)) {
        return app('redirect');
    }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```